# How to use apply function and which function of apply-family?

Tags: r, apply

I'm still struggling with the different apply-function and how they can replace a for-next-loop. What I want to do is sorting a vector with strings (value labels) according to a sorted order of values, in my case odds ratios.

I have odds ratios (unordered) in the "oo" object and the sorted / ordered odds values in the so object. Further, I have value labels sorted in the same order as "oo", which now should be re-orderd to match the values in the "so" object:

```
# sort labels descending in order of
# odds ratio values
oo <- exp(coef(x))[-1]
so <- sort(exp(coef(x))[-1])
nlab <- NULL
for (k in 1:length(categoryLabels)) {
  nlab <- c(nlab, categoryLabels[which(so[k]==oo)])
}
categoryLabels <- nlab
```

e.g.

- "oo" is (0.3, 0.7, 0.5)
- "so" is (0.3, 0.5, 0.7)
- categoryLabels (of oo) is ("A", "B", "C") and should be re-ordered according to "so": ("A", "C", "B")

What I like to know is, if it's possible to replace the for-next-loop by an apply-function, and if so, how?

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: Are the `categoryLabels` elements in the same order as the `oo` elements to start with? If so, `ord <- order(00)` followed by `so <- oo[ord]` and `categoryLabels <- categoryLabels[ord]` should do it. Better would be to turn `oo` into a *named* vector with `names` attribute set to `categoryLabels` and then sort `oo`. Of course this makes the assumption that I enquire about in the first sentence of this comment.

Comment: "Are the categoryLabels elements in the same order as the oo elements to start with?" - Yes, "oo" are "original odds" that contain OR values, and the category labels are related to these ORs (i.e. same 'unordered' order). "so" should be the "sorted odds". The order function works fine, I used the implementation suggested by David.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like all you're trying to do is order `categoryLabels` based on `oo`, which could be done with:

```
categoryLabels = categoryLabels[order(oo)]
```

[order](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/order.html) gives you a vector of indices that, when used to index a vector, will turn it into the sorted order. In your example:

```
oo = c(0.3, 0.7, 0.5)
order(oo)
# [1] 1 3 2
```

Though if we did start with `so` and `oo`, much easier than using any `apply` function in this case would be using [match](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/match.html):

```
categoryLabels = categoryLabels[match(oo, so)]
```

`match` is a function that finds the indices of the first vector in the second vector. In your example:

```
oo = c(0.3, 0.7, 0.5)
so = c(0.3, 0.5, 0.7)
match(oo, so)
# [1] 1 3 2
```

Comment: Thank you, David! Works fine and I again got deeper into R syntax and coding!